# Sending Image through Share Sheet for Whatsapp is not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift5

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` to present the share sheet.

can share the image and text together as expected in all apps except in WhatsApp. There only the text is being shown to send and not the image.

What am I doing wrong here?

```swift
let text = "Hey! Check this out"
let shareSheet = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text, UIImage(named: "Light-HomeScreen")!], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(shareSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the image exists in the assets library?

Comment: @shravan.sukumar yes it exists because it works with other apps just not with WhatsApp

Comment: WhatsApp accepts only an image. Try removing the text and add the image only in the items array and check @jsbeginnerNodeJS

Comment: @shravan.sukumar This works, but how can I send both?

Comment: I don't think that's possible..You can either share an image, link or image separately..

Comment: Weird..........